# Using Gompertz Distribution for Survival Rate Prediction

Tags: forecasting, survival

I have fitted a parametric survival model using Gompertz distribution. In the output, I can get the values for the shape and the rate. I would like to using the shape and the rate to estimate the probability of survival, but not sure how to do that. Please help.

(Admittedly, I have very limited understanding around distribution functions...)

By googling, I was landed on this page. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/flexsurv/versions/1.0.0/topics/Gompertz

Looks like I just need to pass the shape and rate to one of the gompertz distribution functions in R (below). But the question is, which one can tell me the survival rate? What I want to get is the probability of survival at the end of year 1, year 2, and year 3, etc.

"dgompertz gives the density, pgompertz gives the distribution function, qgompertz gives the quantile function, hgompertz gives the hazard function, Hgompertz gives the cumulative hazard function, and rgompertz generates random deviates."

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please provide the parameter values for your model.

Comment: @Todd Here's the Gompertz model parameter estimates outputted in R, using the flexsurvreg function :                           
 
shape =-0.970 
rate   =1.420

Answer (score 1):

##### Answer

For survival models, it generally holds that:
$$
S(t) = 1 - F(t)
$$
where $S$ is the survival function and $F$ the CDF. So you can simply use:

```
1 - pgompertz(q, shape, scale)
```

---

##### More context

For Survival Models / Distributions it holds that:

$$\begin{aligned}
\text{Hazard function}   && \mu(t) &= \underset{\mathrm{d}t \rightarrow 0}{\lim} \frac{P(t \leq T \leq t + \mathrm{d}t | T\geq t)}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{f(t)}{S(t)} = - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\ln \big[S(t)\big] \\
\text{Cumulative Hazard} && M(t) &= \int_0^t \mu(x) \mathrm{d}x  \\
\text{pdf}               && f(t) &= \mu(t) S(t) \\
\text{cdf}               && F(t) &= P(T < t) = \int_{-\infty}^t f(x)  \mathrm{d}x \\
\text{Survival function} && S(t) &= 1- F(t) = \int_t^{\infty}f(x) \mathrm{d}x = e^{-M(t)}\\
\text{Life Expectancy}   && e(t) &= \frac{1}{S(t)} \int_t^\infty S(x) \mathrm{d}x \quad \text{with } e(0) = \int_0^\infty S(x) \mathrm{d}x \quad \text{since} \quad S(0) = 1
\end{aligned}$$

With age $a$ and time of death $T$.

By defining the Gompertz $Hazard$ or $pdf$ in a Survival Model context, we can derive the survival probabilities using the `Survival function` as so:

$$\begin{aligned}
\text{Hazard function}   && \mu(t) &= R e^{\alpha t} \\
\text{pdf}               && f(t) &= R e^{\alpha t} \exp \left[- \frac{R}{\alpha} e^{\alpha t}  \right] \\
\text{cdf}               && F(t) &= 1 - \exp \left[- \frac{R}{\alpha} e^{\alpha t}  \right] \\
\text{Survival function} && S(t) &= \exp \left[-\frac{R}{\alpha} (e^{\alpha t} -1)  \right]
\end{aligned}$$

(See e.g. https://www.monicaalexander.com/posts/2018-02-15-gompertz/

Simply define:

```
survfun_gompertz = function(t, R, alpha){
  exp( -(R/alpha) * ( exp(alpha*t) - 1) )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer to this long-open question. Please double-check whether your `survfun_gompertz` actually represents the Gompertz survival function written just above. Also, the presentation of the Gompertz hazard, pdf, pdf, and survival might be easier to read if you used $t$ to represent time consistently throughout instead of $a$, as it's hard for some of us to distinguish $\alpha$ from $a$.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the recommendations. I fixed the function.